# set visible date in nxg-bootstrap datepicker

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using Angular 7.2.15 and ngx-bootstrap 4.1.1.
I want to set a minimum date and maximum date for the datepicker. the input field also has a placeholder to show the dateformat to the user, no date should be initially set here so the user is forced to select one.

The idea is that we already know the age of the user, so we want to limit the datepicker to his/her birthyear.

the problem I'm having is that when the datepicker is opened, it shows december of the year (of the maxdate). I would like to set the selected date/week/month in the datpicker to avoid showing december. Is it possible to set the date in the datepicker, without affecting the value of the input field?

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="{{'DateFormat' | translate}}" class="form-control" id="birthdate" formControlName="birthdate"
[ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.birthdate.errors }" bsDatepicker 
#dp="bsDatepicker" triggers=""   
               [bsConfig]="{ dateInputFormat: 'DD/MM/YYYY', showWeekNumbers: 
false, maxDate: maxdate, minDate: mindate}"                                      
                [maxDate]="maxdate" [minDate]="mindate" placement="right">
```

**component**

```
...
if (this.age) {
        this.mindate = new Date();
        this.mindate.setFullYear(this.mindate.getFullYear() - this.age, 0, 1);
        this.maxdate = new Date();
        this.maxdate.setFullYear(this.maxdate.getFullYear() - this.age, 11, 31);
        this.selectedDate = this.mindate;
    }
...

    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({           
        birthdate: ['', [Validators.required, DateValidators.validateDateRange(this.mindate, this.maxdate)]],          
    });
```

...

the validateDateRange is a custom method that checks if the selected date is valid and between the mindate and maxdate

Answer (score 0):

In component.ts

```
minRange:Date[];

  ngOnInit() {

    this.mindate = new Date(2019 - this.age, 0, 1);
    this.maxdate = new Date(2019 - this.age, 11, 31);

    this.minRange = [this.mindate, this.maxdate];
  }
```

In HTML, after adding `[(ngModel)]`, it works for me

```
<input
    [className]="class"
    [id]="id"
    [name]="name"
    [value]="val"
    type="text"
    (input)="onChange($event.target.value)"
    (blur)="onTouched()"
    bsDaterangepicker
    triggers="keydown click"
    [formControl]="control"
    [(ngModel)]="minRange"
    [bsConfig]="{ containerClass : 'theme-default', rangeInputFormat: 'MMM DD, YYYY', maxDate: maxdate, minDate: mindate}"
  >
```

Comment: adding the [(ngModel)] also sets the date in the input field I only want to set the visible date/week in the date picker pop up. I feel like this should be a parameter as well, but I haven't found anything that works so far.

Comment: Issue created for ngx-bootstrap - https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/5266

Comment: Actually I already had one for the datepicker - https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/5265 , but I guess the date range picker will have the same issue. Thanks for helping.